# Ability to preview video and get the seeked time of the video before uploading

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I would like to give the users the ability to select video poster for the video before its uploaded.

Uploading the video:

1. Choose a file
2. Either of these two case scenario:

   - The first is easy. If user doesn't want to select a poster, then the default will automatically be the first second of the video.
   - Or if the user wants, then show video scrubber/slider with its preview. And get the duration of the seeked video.
3. Submit/Upload

So, my question is how do I display a slider to seek through and get its seek duration. Hope I was clear, if not please ask. Thank you.